# Updating ATI HD 5970 Graphics card - version errors?

Tags: graphics-card, computer-building, updates

I'm having an issue...My system specs is:

- Intel i7 960
- 6GM Corair XMS RAM
- ATI HD5970 graphics card
- Intel dx58so motherboard
- Cooler Master HAF 922 case
- 1.5TB Seagate hard drive
- Windows Vista x86 (32-bit).

Here is my issue:  when I go to AMD/ATI website to update my graphics card - it doesn't. when I type `DxDiag` and then click on `display` it tell me my version is  `8.17.0` and its on `10.10.0` for the latest version. How can I get `8.17.0` too `10.10.0`? I figure it would have done that after I updated the driver for my graphics card. Thanks.

Comment: This is really a question for Superuser.com and I expect it will be migrated there shortly. Server Fault is for questions "... about your servers, your networks, or desktops you support, ..." (quoted from the FAQ).

Comment: "When i go to amd/ati website to update my graphic card it doesn't." Does it give you an error message? What doesn't it do: detect your card? download the update? apply the update? A little bit more information about the problem would help.

Answer (score 1):

The version "10.10" is effectively the driver package release date, as in year 10, month 10. Last months drivers would be 10.9 and so on, and last years driver packages were 9.1 through to 9.12. The actual driver and program versions within the package can and will vary and quite likely will not agree with the 10.10 version number you see as a customer downloading the drivers.

Admitedly this makes it difficult to ensure that you have the latest version of the drivers installed but you should be able to see the driver date on the same page of device manager as the driver version you found that that should agree with the year.month policy that ATi adopted for their driver releases.

nVidia are slightly better about their driver versions, but not by much. I have the 258.96 driver version but device manager shows "Driver Version: 8.17.12.5896 " which is basically the driver version with 8.17.1 added to the front for some reason.

Chances are that unless the driver installer comes up win an error then you have the latest drivers.

Comment: +1 Also the drivers are outdated: Latest 5970 32bit Vista drivers as of writing are 11.3: http://sites.amd.com/us/game/downloads/Pages/radeon_vista-32.aspx